# PowerShell can't create folder on network mount

Tags: permissions, powershell

I've create a drive with the Letter Z: and shared it so that the Network Path is: `\\GOELA2682012SRV\srv2012r2`

I now want to create a folder on there using PowerShell.

This doesn't work:
`New-Item -Path "\\GOELA2682012SRV\srv2012r2\Users\test" -ItemType Directory`

While this does work: 
`New-Item -Path "Z:\Users\test" -ItemType Directory`

Why?

Comment: Does `mkdir \\GOELA2682012SRV\srv2012r2\Users\test` work in cmd.exe?

Comment: Yes it does @grawity

Comment: Does prepending `FileSystem::` to the UNC path work?  `FileSystem::\\GOELA2682012SRV\srv2012r2\Users\test`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try prepending `FileSystem::` to the UNC path, so it becomes `FileSystem::\\GOELA2682012SRV\srv2012r2\Users\test`

> PowerShell’s behavior can be a little bit funny when you pass a UNC
>   path to certain cmdlets. PowerShell doesn’t recognize these paths as
>   “rooted” because they’re not on a PSDrive; as such, whatever provider
>   is associated with PowerShell’s current location will attempt to
>   handle them. For example:
>
> ```
> Set-Location C:
> Get-ChildItem -Path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$
>
> Set-Location HKLM:
> Get-ChildItem -Path \\$env:COMPUTERNAME\c$
> ```
>
> The first command works fine (assuming you have a c$ share enabled and
>   are able to access it), and the second command gives a “Cannot find
>   path” error, because the Registry provider tried to work with the UNC
>   path instead of the FileSystem provider. You can get around this
>   problem by prefixing the UNC path with “FileSystem::”, which will make
>   PowerShell use that provider regardless of your current location.

[PowerShell Gotcha: UNC paths and Providers](http://powershell.org/wp/2014/02/20/powershell-gotcha-unc-paths-and-providers/)

Comment: This is crazy...worked for me.

Comment: Saved my life - calling a powershell script from SQL agent, which in turn used an imported cmdlet. This was the solution.